# Custom module routing is going to page not found

Tags: routes, 9

I have a custom module that i'd like to display my webform on a certain page but it keeps sending me to a 'Page not found'.

folder structure is;

```
modules/custom/custom_webform_display
-custom_webform_display.info.yml
-custom_webform_display.module
-custom_webform_display.routing.yml
--src
---Controller
----CustomWebformDisplayController.php
--templates
---custom-webform-display-page.html.twig
```

info.yml

```
name: 'Custom Webform Display'
type: module
description: 'Displays a webform in a custom page template.'
core_version_requirement: ^9 || ^10
package: Custom
dependencies:
  - webform:webform
```

.module

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function custom_webform_template_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'custom_webform_template_page' => [
      'variables' => [
        'webform' => NULL,
        'webform_content' => NULL,
      ],
      'template' => 'custom-webform-template-page',
      'path' => $path . '/templates',
    ],
  ];
}


/**
 * Page callback for the custom webform template page.
 */
function custom_webform_template_page_callback($webform_id) {
  $webform = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform')->load($webform_id);

  if ($webform) {
    // Ensure the webform content is a render array before rendering.
    $webform_content = $webform->getSubmissionForm()->render();
    $webform_content = Markup::create($webform_content);

    $build = [
      '#theme' => 'custom_webform_template_page',
      '#webform' => $webform,
      '#webform_content' => $webform_content,
    ];
    return $build;
  } else {
    // If the webform with the given ID does not exist, return a 404 page.
    throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException();
  }
}
```

.routing.yml

```
custom_webform_display.display:
  path: '/custom-webform'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_webform_display\Controller\CustomWebformDisplayController::displayWebform'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

.page.html.twig

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default template file for displaying a webform in a custom page template.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - webform: The rendered webform.
 */
#}

<div class="custom-webform-display">
  {{ webform }}
</div>
```

Controller.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_webform_display\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

/**
 * Controller for displaying a webform in a custom page template.
 */
class CustomWebformDisplayController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Displays the webform in a custom page template.
   *
   * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
   *   The rendered webform.
   */
  public function displayWebform() {
    // Load the webform by its ID. Replace 'your_webform_id' with the actual webform ID.
    $webform_id = 'contact';
    $webform = \Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform::load($webform_id);

    // Check if the webform exists and is open.
    if ($webform && $webform->isOpen()) {
      // Render the webform.
      $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($webform);
      $rendered_form = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($form);

      // Create a custom page template and replace 'custom_webform_display_page' with your template name.
      $output = [
        '#theme' => 'custom_webform_display_page',
        '#webform' => $rendered_form,
      ];

      return new Response(\Drupal::service('renderer')->render($output));
    }

    // If the webform doesn't exist or is closed, display an error message or redirect to another page.
    return new Response($this->t('The webform is not available at the moment.'));
  }

}
```

Comment: Where exactly you pass the webform ID?

Comment: The code does not show in which way is `custom_webform_template_page_callback()` called. The documentation comment describes it as page callback, but in Drupal 9 a page callback is a controller method, not a plain function.

Comment: webform_id is missing from the route path.

Comment: Thank you all so much, i've made some changes to my module however i'm still getting a page not found, am I still missing something? I've updated my original post with all of my code. The webform ID is 'contact' that i want to display on /custom-webform

Comment: Can you confirm that 1) You are browsing the site on path /custom-webform and 2) that you rebuilt the site caches?

Comment: yep I browse to /custom-webform and yep rebuilt caches (several times) and tried in incognito mode

Answer (score 0):

I changed my displaywebform function to just this and it now works;

```
  public function displayWebform() {


      $webform = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform')->load('contact');
      $webform = $webform->getSubmissionForm();
      
      return $webform;
    }
```